# What happens when two different annotations have the same name?

Tags: java, annotations

I never encountered the case and now I'm wondering: what happens when/if two different annotations have the same name?   *(I'll give here an example using an annotation provided by IntelliJ but the question is really generic so I'm not tagging it 'IntelliJ')*

For example the first sentence here:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-4959

says:

> Many libraries have their own @NotNull
>   annotations (intellij,
>   hibernate-validation, ..).

What happens exactly if I wanted to use, say, both IntelliJ's `@NotNull` and Hibernate's `@NotNull`? *(once again @NotNull is just an example where I happen to find a clash)*

Are they incompatible? If they're incompatible, is it for the whole project?

This is something I'm really not familiar with...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no ambiguity, because the annotation's package name will be specified in an import or on the annotation itself.

[JSR-305](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) addresses your specific example. It seeks a standard set of annotations, and refers specifically to FindBugs' and IntelliJ's nullability annotations.

> Nullness annotations (e.g., @NonNull
>   and @CheckForNull). Both FindBugs and
>   IntelliJ already support their own
>   versions of nullness annotations.

Answer (score 10):

In such a case you need to specify the full qualified name, e.g

```
@bar.baz.Foo 
@org.fubar.Foo
void myMethod() {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't as the full package is part of the name. The effect is that you can only import one and will have to refer to any other with its fully qualified name. Like so

```
@NotNull
@com.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
public Object ...
```

Comment: +1... Ouch.  It sure looks ugly/verbose using the fully qualified name :-/

Answer (score 1):

That won't matter since each annotation's full qualified name won't be the same. You can declare the qualified name on the `import` section.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the same for two classes/interafces/enums/annotations with the same name.  They should appear in different packages. If they are in the same package (e.g. different versions) but different jar/directories, then the first one found in the classpath is chosen.